# How can key released (key listener) be implemented on codename one

Tags: keylistener, codenameone

Am trying to implement an on key released event on codename one apparently it seems not to be included in its library. Is there a way/another way I can get to do this ? This java code will not work.

```
 protected void onMain_PostalCodeKeyReleased(Component c, KeyEvent event) {

        Dialog.show("WORK", "Hey", "OK", null);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/WI5W-DRWdpg/ebo_PEgQtZcJ

For your case you need `DataChangeListener` since iOS has no keys.